# Strange!!Getting multiple payload tabs under Networks tab in chrome browsers Developer Tool

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Getting multiple payload tabs under Networks tab in chrome browsers Developer Tool.
Anybody knows root cause for this?.
Chrome Version: `96.0.4664.55 (Official Build) (x86_64).`

[image]

Comment: Looks like a bug - [you might want to report it](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop).